# Nested dicts in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

im having a very frustrating problem.
I would like to get all the categories and sub-categories, sub-sub categories etc.. from wikipedia and put that in a huge nested dict.

My problem is that for example if i find the top categories (the category: All), i can iterate the loop again with the found subcategories but i cant get them to nest in my dict.

Is there someone who can provide some help or see the error.?

Thanks in advance,

```
import requests  # http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

category = 'Categorie:Alles'

def wiki_api_request(category):
    url = ('http://nl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=%s&cmlimit=500')%category
    return url

category_dict = {}

def crawl(category_name, _dict):
    url = wiki_api_request(category_name)

    _url = requests.get(url)


    extract = _url.json()

    category_amount = 0
    if 'query' in extract:
        category_list_json = extract['query']['categorymembers']
        _dict[category_name] = {category['title'] for category in category_list_json}

        for category in category_list_json:
            if 'Categorie:' in category['title']:
                crawl(category['title'], _dict[category_name] ** <-This gives an error**)
                break

crawl(category, category_dict)
print category_dict
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-b8027c8281eb> in <module>()
     29                 break
     30 
---> 31 crawl(category, category_dict)
     32 print category_dict

<ipython-input-40-b8027c8281eb> in crawl(category_name, _dict)
     26         for category in category_list_json:
     27             if 'Categorie:' in category['title']:
---> 28                 crawl(category['title'], _dict[category_name])
     29                 break
     30 

<ipython-input-40-b8027c8281eb> in crawl(category_name, _dict)
     22     if 'query' in extract:
     23         category_list_json = extract['query']['categorymembers']
---> 24         _dict[category_name] = {category['title'] for category in category_list_json}
     25 
     26         for category in category_list_json:

TypeError: 'set' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: what error? edit you Q. please.

Comment: Why do you import `bs4.BeautifulSoup` if you don't use it?

Comment: thats for later in the assignement

Comment: please describe the json structure of the fetched url data

Comment: As your error message states, the error is 5 lines above the location you indicated in the source.

Comment: You could probably have identified the problem yourself by trying to boil your code down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or by [systematic debugging](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{category['title'] for category in category_list_json}` is a set comprehension, not a dictionary comprehension. So the result assigned to `_dict` will be a `set`.

You probably want a dictionary with empty dictionaries as values as the result of the comprehension, so do

```
{category['title']:{} for category in category_list_json}
```

or more explicitly

```
{category['title']:dict() for category in category_list_json}
```

Comment: yes, upvoted. As per the error shown `TypeError: 'set' object does not support item assignment`